# Linux: bad throughput when packets received in unicast

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I'm doing some mesure to know the throughput of my network card with different application (iperf, pktgen, tcpdump, pktgen-dpdk, etc.). I have a computer (host A) that sends 64 bytes UDP packet to host B on a 1Gb/s line.

I would like to mesure the receive throughput of host B. I use tcpdump (but I noticed the same behaviour with Wireshark and Ostinato).

When I send packets in unicast (mac and ip of host B), host B can only receive 1Mpps (million packets per second)
When I send packet with different dst mac address or different dst ip address, host B can receive 1.48Mpps (the max theoretical throughput).

The strangest thing is, if dst mac and dst ip are correct (host B) BUT src Ip if from another network of host B, host B receive also 1.48Mpps.

I don't understand why.  Does anybody have any idea ?

I have made a graph with the value returned by tcpdump in the different scenarios (packet captured, packet dropped by interface, etc.)

[Received throughput without flow control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2dMC.png)

[Received throughput withflow control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSTKE.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Is host B CPU running at 100% - if so, one possible explanation is that  when dst mac/ip is correct, the Host B networking stack will process the packet which takes more CPU cycles than when dst mac/ip is incorrect and the stack wouldn't process the packet. Also in the former case if there is no process listening on the dst UDP port, the stack will send a ICMP back (read more CPU cycles). Regarding changing src ip, I'm not sure - what were the actual IP address values? Same subnet or different?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. Yes I also think the same. The Kernel processes the packets when the addresses are correct (IP and MAC) and send back a ICMP Error because the port is close. I opened a process (netcat) listening on the port, and the throughput was 1.48Mpps with Wireshark and Ostinato